# Is there a way to extract the data points from a raster image of a line plot?

Tags: plotting

This might be a bad question to ask and if it is I am happy to close it.

My question is if there is a way to get the data points of a plot if I could recognize the hex color of the line plot using some program like Inkscape. I feel like the answer is no for a raster but yes for a vector. Again, sorry for the vague question.

Comment: And there exist quite a number of related posts in this site, don't miss those links on the right side of the linked page.

Comment: @xzczd thanks for the links. I am going to try to solve this with those before I ask the question. thanks.